# What can Substrate and Polkadot do for me?

Tags: substrate-node-template, consensus, learning

What is the best and quickest way, for a layman, who has very little,
to no experience, at all, in coding and/or developing, to play catch-up, so that he/she might be brought-up-to-speed, enough to allow them a level of comfort while using a site, such as this one. –Books, websites, articles, program's, etc. Any, and all, input will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-index, and https://docs.substrate.io/learn/welcome-to-substrate/